# Best Practice WIth Apostrophe in Php Mysql Queries

Tags: php, mysql, apostrophe

Apostrophes can be a pain while sending sql update queries in from php when there's a non-matching "'" inside the string.
What is the best practice to overcome this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Use PDO/MySQLi with prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best practice is to use prepared statements, but you can use the [`addslashes($string)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) and [`stripslashes($string)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) functions too.

Comment: Using prepared statements is much safer since there can be a way around those functions

Comment: This solution might be more practical because it does not require installing extensions.

Comment: it is much safer to use other extensions which you have to install rather than use these functions, it's only for your SQL injection safety!

Comment: As I said, I think that the best practice is to use prepared statements, but if you can't at least you can use this functions.

Answer (score 6):

PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username');
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_GET['username']));
```

MySQLi:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = s');
$query->bind_param('s', $_GET['username']);
```

These extensions have built-in functions for creating prepared queries which let you use quotes and apostrophes without any problems.

Comment: This sounds good. I haven't tried it yet though.

Comment: +1, because your explanation was so simple and painless, I finally decided to switch to prepared statements!